# How to change GRANTABLE in SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES table?

Tags: db2

How to grant/revoke or change this 'GRANTABLE' parameter for a user in table 'SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES' from 'Y' to 'N' or vice-ver?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all your related questions? Have you read https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005817.html as a starter?

Comment: My only aim is to set 'GRANTABLE' parameter to 'N' for one specific row. How can I do that? I don't have much knowledge of DB2 and I need to set few values only nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Citation from the [REVOKE (table, view, or nickname privileges)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000990.html) statement description:

> - **Revoking WITH GRANT OPTION**: The only way to revoke the WITH GRANT OPTION is to revoke the privilege itself and then grant it again without specifying WITH GRANT OPTION.

Answer (score 0):

For object-types that support grantable permissions, the relevant GRANT statement has to be issued with the ' WITH GRANT OPTION ' by an authorisation-id that already has that option or has relevent ACCESSCTRL/SECADM/CONTROL for the object.

When the ' WITH GRANT OPTION ' clause is present on a grant statement and the authorisation-id that's performing the statement is allowed to use it, then the relevant row in the catalog table (sysibmadm.privileges) will have a 'Y' in the grantable column.  Without that option, the value will be 'N'.

If you seek to have N for grantable in a specific row, then two statements are needed (by suitably entitled authorisation id), first is to revoke the permission, second is to grant the relevant permission (and this time omit the ' with grant option' ). This is valid for simple cases only, so might not suit your environment. In particular, revoking permissions can invalidate some other objects and cause run time errors, so be aware of the risks.

If you don't have much knowledge of Db2, it is wise to leave database privilege administration to suitably skilled people.

Refer to the online free Knowledge center for your version of Db2 and your platform for all the details.

Comment: My only aim is to set 'GRANTABLE' parameter to 'N' for one specific row. How can I do that? I don't have much knowledge of DB2 and I need to set few values only nothing else.